# Good practice about numerical precision

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

In one of my calculations, I get -1.11022*10^-16 as one of my eigenvalues for a matrix. It's essentially zero and I suppose I could use [SetPrecision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) to make it zero but I wonder what's a good practice here? Should I maybe include something at the beginning of the code to specify precision for everything? Or do I just set arbitrary precision when I feel my expression is not simplified enough?

I'm pretty new to Mathematica.

---

As others have commented, after trying in different calculations, I think use \Chop after each calculation is the best and safest way.One can also explicitly specify the digits to keep.

Comment: You could apply `Chop`.

Comment: I do not believe that you really want to ess with precision here. You just want to push values close to `0.` to `0.`. This can be done by `Threshold` and by specifying a suitable tolerance as second argument.

Comment: Thank you guys. Is there a way to Chop/Threshold the whole notebook? Or I just apply these functions after whatever output I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica has three different types of numbers.

Exact numbers, e.g.

```
5, Sqrt[2], 4/3, ...
```

Machine precision numbers

```
1.23, 5., .4566, ...
```

And numbers with a set precision

```
5.`16, 1.2345`5, ...
```

You can tell what kind of number something is by applying `Precision` to it.

If all your input number have an set precision, then the output of you eigenvalue computation should also have a finite precision attached to it. This will allow you to distinguish between an eigenvalue that is really small an one that is consistent with zero within the expected accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I should set every input with a precision as " `some number?" And how can Sqrt[2] and 4/3 be exact??